# Tomcat not starting in linux ---permission denied to run startup.sh

Tags: linux, tomcat, permission-denied

I pasted tomcat folder in Linux machine. User is root . When I go to bin folder and execute `./startup.sh` I'm getting an `error:permission denied`. [This is what I got]

How to rectify this issue.

[image: png]

Answer (score 19):

give:

```
chmod -R 777 startup.sh
```

Then error will come as:Cannot find ./catalina.sh
then give:

```
chmod -R 777 catalina.sh
```

Tomcat will start.
the problem was because there was no permission for executing. u can see if permission is there or not by giving:

```
ls -l
```

Comment: Don't use `777` though, that gives everything permission, to read, write and execute. Use `a+x` to allow anyone to execute or even `u+x` so it's only the current user.

Answer (score 12):

As color of file name is white, I suppose file is not executable; try the following command
`ls -l`
It gives you file list with its permission. Try using command

```
chmod a+x startup.sh
```

If still permission denied. Try

```
sudo chmod a+x startup.sh
```

Then try using 
./startup.sh
If still permission denied. Then try

```
sudo ./startup.sh
```

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Verify, that your filesystem with the new tomcat folder isn't mounted with "noexec". Please run a "ls -l", "file start.sh" and a "head start.sh" .

Tom

Answer (score 0):

It is also worthwhile to check which bash you are using with

```
which bash
```

This is because you might see the error

```
Cannot find ./catalina.sh
```

when your bash is **/usr/bin/bash** but is working perfectly fine when bash is **/usr/bash**